# iOS6 Orientation

Tags: ios, orientation, landscape, ios6, portrait

I have a question about iOS 6 Orientation.Here is my file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8q9tghdutge2nu/Orientations_iOS6.zip

In this sample code,I want to make the `MasterViewController` only has a Portrait Orientation and the `DetailViewController` has a Portrait Orientation,Landscape Orientation.

I know iOS 6 Orientation is controlled by top-most controller.

So I custom a `UINavigationController(CustomNavigationController)`, set supportedInterfaceOrientations and shouldAutorotate in that class.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    if([[self topViewController] isKindOfClass:[DetailViewController class]]){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Everything is fine except when `DetailViewController` at Landscape Orientation press back button,`MasterViewController` will show the Landscape Orientation.

Can I let `MasterViewController` always show Portrait Orientation and `DetailViewController` can has many orientation?

thanks!

Comment: I find the solution today.
set this in your CustomNavigationController
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self topViewController] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

then set this on MasterViewController
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

Comment: If you found the answer to your question, you should post your answer as an answer, and mark it as correct, it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this work as you suggested in your comment on the question. The problem is that the default UINavigatonController does not use the value of the top view controller, so you need to override it by creating a base class and setting it in the Storyboard as the base class.

Below is the code that I use.

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

I also have a base class for the rest of my View Controllers to default the behavior to use the Portrait orientation. I can override these methods for iOS 5 and 6 in any view controllers which support more than Portrait orientation.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks! Brennan,
I also collect others way to do that in my blog.
http://blog.hanpo.tw/2012/09/ios-60-orientation.html

Here's the two others way.

**1.add a Category to UINavigationController**

```
    @implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
    }

    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

    - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    {
        return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    }

    @end
```

**2.Swap Method Implementations (Made by spoletto)**

https://gist.github.com/3725118

Comment: Upvote because reading your post led me to finally fixing the ios6 device rotation issues I was having. I want my app to be Portrait only, EXCEPT when presenting a full screen video. My solution was to set Supported Orientations to Portrait in the info.plist, overriding the tab bar subclass to return Portrait orientation/Portrait orientation mask/autorotates NO. This worked because the tab bar is the parent view controller! Thanks.